# Scala Parser Combinators <~ ~>ignores all previous statements

Tags: scala, parsing, parser-combinators

I am using the scala parser combinator for extracting identifiers ("a" and "ACCOUNT_ID") in the input string. When I use ~> it ignores all the previous parts of the string instead of the immediate predecessor string. Can someone please help me on extracting the 2 identifiers from the input string using Scala Parser Combinators? Appreciate your help

```
class QParser extends JavaTokenParsers with RegexParsers {
def join: Parser [Any] = opt(ident) ~ (opt("(")) ~ ident ~ "." ~> ident <~     opt(",") <~ ident <~ opt(")") 
}

object QueryParser extends QParser {
def main(args: Array[String]){
     println(parseAll(join,"convert(a.ACCOUNT_ID, string)"))
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Infix operators that don't end with `:` are left-associative, so `a ~ b ~> c` is parenthesized as `(a ~ b) ~> c`. If you want something else, you need to add parentheses yourself.

In this case you want `opt("(")) ~ ident ~ ("." ~> ident) <~ ...`, so that only the `"."` is the left operand of `~>`.

Comment: Got it and it works perfectly. Would it possible to provide solution using ":". I could not get the context of using ":" in combinators.

Comment: @Sathish Could you clarify what you mean by that?

Comment: My question is how to ":" in parser combinators. BTW, I am encountering issue while passing string "a.ACCOUNT_ID" instead of "convert(a.ACCOUNT_ID, string)" for the                                                              `def joinExp: Parser[Any] = opt(ident) ~> opt("(") ~> ident ~ ("." ~> ident <~ opt(",") <~ ident <~ opt(")"))` getting error _[1.32] failure: string matching regex `\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*' expected but `.' found_

Comment: @Sathish I'm afraid that didn't make your question clearer to me. Are you asking how to use a colon as part of your parsed syntax? The same you're doing with "." and "," now: you just write ":" where you need it. Or are you asking which types your parsers should have (i.e. what should go after the `:` in your Scala code)? `Parser[T]` where `T` is the type you want your result to be.

Comment: @Sathish Regarding your second question: After adding the parentheses as I suggested, your code works fine for me. It prints `[1.30] parsed: (((Some(convert)~Some(())~a)~ACCOUNT_ID)`.

Comment: Thank you. It works. My bad. I didn't put it correctly. Do you recommend some links where I can get learn about scala parser combinators? I couldn't find many in google..